# Pure JS synchronous AJAX call to a remote site

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

This is what I got:

```
function fetchJson(url, method, params) {
    var request,
        method = method || 'GET',
        params = params || null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    request.open(method, url, false);
    request.send(params);

    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200)
        return JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    return null;
}
```

This is supposed to fetch a json **synchronously**.

However, when I run this in Opera 12 to fetch a Twitter search Json I get an unhandled NETWORK_ERR thrown.

Is it possible to write a pure-JS synchronous ajax function that can fetch json from any location?

Comment: synchronous requests are not recommended as javascript is single-threaded and it could block the GUI. Why don't just use asyn requests?

Comment: Its a html game and I want to load some resources before continuing initialization

Answer (score 1):

Calls using `XMLHttpRequest` are subject to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prevents cross-origin calls unless both the server and browser support [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) ([most browsers do](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors), although IE8 and IE9's support is broken, requiring use of the MS-specific `XDomainRequest` object) and the server grants access to the origin of your document.

Absent CORS, there is no direct *synchronous* solution. You'd have to go indirectly through your own server.

If the twitter feed supports [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), though, you can use that, which is asynchronous. Asynchronous requests are generally best in any case.

So summarizing the above, the answer to

> Is it possible to write a pure-JS synchronous ajax function that can fetch json from any location?

...is "Yes, if the server supports CORS and allows requests from your origin, and you're using a browser supporting CORS; no if not, you have to go through your own server or do an asynchronous request."

Comment: so shortly - my code is correct, it's the header that's missing?

Comment: @Kiel: Glancing through it, it seems fine. Again, on IE8 or IE9 if you wanted CORS you'd need `XDomainRequest` instead. But fundamentally: You're probably better off using JSONP (which I expect Twitter supports) and making it asynchronous. 99.99% of the time, there's just no reason for a synchronous ajax call, and they tend to make for a bad user experience by locking up the browser's UI thread. (The other 0.01% of the time are quite special cases.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, You have to use jsonp... CrossDomain communication...

I made pure javascript function for you... You can have a look and free to use it

https://github.com/toosha01/ajax-javascript